# How to override standard slds class for textarea in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, slds, lightning-textarea

I have a textarea field in my LWC. I'm trying to set height for the textarea but no luck.

```
<lightning-textarea name={record.id} class="slds-p-horizontal--xx-small" variant="label-hidden" onblur={updateValue} onchange={valueChange} value={value} disabled={isdisabled}></lightning-textarea>
```

When I tried to override slds-textarea class, instead of increasing the height of the content, it increase the entire area.

```
.slds-textarea {
    height: 250px;
    max-height: 250px;
}
```

I've given description for the images added here but not sure why its no visible. First image is the actual output and the second image is the expected output

[image: Actual Output]

[image: Expected Output]

Comment: use a regular HTML textfield?

Comment: thanks alot glls. It worked !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular [HTML text area](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp), since lightning components in the end render html elements that use web api's and leverage slds styling (amongst other things)